# EF Code First - Get POCO from Proxy

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Question:

**Is it possible when dealing with dynamic proxy to pull out the underlying POCO when we need to serialize them?**

Rationale:

I have a requirement to serialize (XML) my POCO entities using EF Code First but quickly found that `DbContext` creates dynamic proxy for my POCO and that makes it hard to serialize.

I have tried the following:

1. Disable proxy creation in the `DbContext` and work only with pure POCO. This allows me to serialize the instances any way I like. The only catch is that navigational properties are not being tracked, therefore, I must attach all related entities manually when I want to save otherwise new entities will always be created (see code example).
2. Implement `ISerializable` interface on the POCO to manually handle serialization. This is a lot of work and is not a sustainable solution.

Code example.

```
// Attach and update tags
foreach (var tag in entity.Tags)
{
    Context.Entry(tag).State = Context.Tags.Any(t => t.ID == tag.ID)
                                    ? EntityState.Modified
                                    : EntityState.Added;
}

// Attach and update state.
Context.Entry(entity).State = Context.Resources.Any(x => x.ID == entity.ID)
                                    ? EntityState.Modified
                                    : EntityState.Added;
```

As you can imagine, the complexity can get out of hand when my entity have more relationships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible when dealing with dynamic proxy to pull out the
>   underlying POCO when we need to serialize them?

No because there is no underlying POCO - the proxy is not a wrapper around entity instance. It is entity instance directly.

You can use `DataContractSerializer` and [`ProxyDataContractResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.proxydatacontractresolver.aspx) to serialize proxied POCOs but serializing proxied entities sounds like you are trying to serialize entities with lazy loading enabled - that can serialize much more than you expect because every property will be lazy loaded recursively until there is no single non-loaded navigation property in the whole object graph.

You must also handle circular references when using `DataContractSerializer` by marking your entities with `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` and every serializable property with `[DataMember]`.

> The only catch is that navigational properties are not being tracked

Entities without proxy are tracked as well. The tracking is dependent on entity being attached not entity being proxied.

> I must attach all related entities manually when I want to save

You must always attach deserialized entities if you want to persist them.