# How to get EF POCOs from System.Data.Entities.DynamicProxies

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, poco

My question is the [same as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382982/ef-code-first-get-poco-from-proxy)

However, I don't really see a solution there. Lets say I have a simple model with two POCOs, Country and State.

```
public class Country
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class State 
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the repository to .GetStateByCode(myCode), it retrieves a dynamic proxy object. I want to send that over the wire using a WCF service to my client. The dynamic proxy is not a know type so it fails.

Here are my alternatives. I can set ProxyCreationEnabled to false on the context and then my .GetStateByCode(myCode) gives me a POCO which is great. However, the navigation property in the POCO to Country is then NULL (not great).

Should I new up a state POCO and manually populate and return that from the dynamic proxy that is returned from the repository? Should I try to use AutoMapper to map the dynamic proxy objects to POCOs? Is there something I'm totally missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer from Ladislav Mrnka is clear.  The Warnings Still apply. Even with this idea below. Becareful what gets picked Up.   He just didnt include , if you want to proceed how to easily get data from Object a to object B.  That is question at hand really.

Sample solution

See nuget package **ValueInjecter**    (not the only tool that can do this... but very easy to use)
it allows easy copying of One object to another especially with the same properties and types. 
 ( remember the lazy loading / navigation implications).

**So vanilla option is :**

```
 var PocoObject = new Poco();
 PocoObject.InjectFrom(DynamicProxy); // copy contents of DynamicProxy to PocoObject
```

**but check the default behaviour and consider a custom rule**

```
     var PocoObject = new Poco();
     PocoObject.InjectFrom<CopyRule>(DynamicProxy);

 public class CopyRule : ConventionInjection
    {
        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            bool usePropertry;   // return if the property it be included in inject process
            usePropertry = c.SourceProp.Name == "Id";  // just an example
            //or
            // usePropertry = c.SourceProp.Type... == "???"
            return usePropertry;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess it was the sample I was really looking for. Thanks a bundle! ValueInjector is awesome.

Comment: The only drawback with this type of solution is how to support two-way transport of the data. How do you get the data from POCO back to an attached dynamic proxy?

Comment: @ qujck : same concept... just reverse direction   get the attached Object from context, then Inject AttachedObject from returned POCO.  Let EF do the change tracking